# How to parse a complex element into a Map, using a attribute as key and the whole element as value, in JAXB Adapter

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I would like to parse a list of complex XML elements into a Map, where the key would be an attribute and the value the whole object/element.

Here is an example of my XML:

```
<product>
    <documents>
        <document code="100" clazz="DocumentA">
            <properties>
                <property name="PropA" value="123" />
                <property name="PropB" value="qwerty" />
                <property name="PropC" value="ABC" />
            </properties>
        </document>
    </documents>
</product>
```

The example of my class Document:

```
public class Document {
    private Integer code;
    private String clazz;
    private List<Propertiy> properties;

    //getters and setters...
}
```

I don't know if it's possible, but i would like to parse document elements into a Map, where the key is the attriute code.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an adapter. Let's start building up the POJOs according to your xml. First you have the product:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Product {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "documents")
    @XmlElement(name = "document")
    private List<Document> documents;
}
```

Then documents in that product:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Document {

    @XmlAttribute
    private Integer code;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String clazz;
    @XmlElement(name = "properties")
    private Properties properties;

}
```

Inside the properties we use the adapter in order to get the desired Map:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Properties {

    @XmlElement(name = "property")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyMapAdapter.class)
    private Map<String, String> properties;
}
```

Our adapter would take the incoming xml in a way that would understand it and turn adapt it to something else (i.e. map). So let's create first a POJO for the property as in xml:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Property {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then we use it in the adapter:

```
public class MyMapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Property, Map<String, String>> {

    private HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> unmarshal(Property v) throws Exception {
        hashMap.put(v.getName(), v.getValue());
        return hashMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Property marshal(Map<String, String> v) throws Exception {
        // do here actions for marshalling if u also marshal
        return null;
    }
}
```

Running this, would unmarshal the payload and it would have the values in the map as desired. Hope it helps